# Jmeter: Recall HTTP sampler request if a particalar string is not found in response cookie

Tags: java, while-loop, jmeter

I have to implement a scenario where i have to call the same request at max for 5 times if it fails and based on the response i am writing some thing in a file. 
Failure happens when a string is not found from cookie which i am capturing as regular exp.

To resolve this , i have added while loop with counter but the script works till 50000 iteration and then gives Out of memory error. 
If i dont put while loop to recall the same request for 5 times, then same script works for 1 million with same JVM without any issue.

Looks like While controller in Jmeter is somehow consuming more memory and throwing out of memory.

Is there any option to recall the same HTTP request through Beanshell Post processor?

Answer (score 0):

1. Approach using [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) and [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) combination:

   - While Controller: condition `${__javaScript(${counter} < 5 && "${foo}" != "bar",)}`

     - Counter: Start `1`, Increment `1`, Reference Name `counter`
     - Your Sampler

   Assuming above setup `Your Sampler` will be executed either 5 times or until when `${foo}` variable value not equal to `bar`, whatever comes the first. See [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) for comprehensive explanation and more examples.
2. If you are still looking for Beanshell way you can use something like:

   ```
   if (!prev.getResponseDataAsString().contains("foo")) {
       ctx.getCurrentSampler().sample(null);
   }
   ```

   Above code being placed into [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) will execute the parent sampler one more time if there will not be `foo` substring in the response, however this way you won't be able to see execution result in listeners and it won't be stored into .jtl file, basically you will have only one execution.

Comment: Thanks for quick answers. Actually I have added the first solution and getting out of memory after 50000 records read from csv file. If i dont put the while loop with this condition, it reads all 1 million records from csv and complete the transaction without any error but in this case i wont be able to retry for 5 times in case of failure. So i wanted to check any alternative solution to do the same without While loop.

Comment: I have a question for Approach 2, if i add this in beashell postProcessor, will it capture regular expression and will it again come to post processor for failed sampler? Is there any way to put a logic like counter here?